# operation time out connection to IBM iot service

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, ibm-cloud, raspbian, iot

I was trying run the python script on my raspberry pi. And my device is also already connected on bluemix. At first, I could able to run the script but now I got the following error.

---

2016-11-14 06:46:30,490   ibmiotf.application.Client  WARNING Unable to encrypt    messages because TLSv1.2 is unavailable (MQTT over SSL requires at least Python    v2.7.9 or 3.4 and openssl v1.0.1)
2016-11-14 06:46:40,571   ibmiotf.application.Client  CRITICAL Operation timed o   ut connecting to the IBM Internet of Things service: 1tlj3z.messaging.internetof   things.ibmcloud.com
Operation timed out connecting to the IBM Internet of Things service: 1tlj3z.mes   saging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com

```
PIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
client = None
def myCommandCallback(cmd):
if cmd.event == "light":
```

payload = json.loads(cmd.payload)

```
 command = payload["command"]
print command
if command == "on":
GPIO.output(17, True)
```

elif command == "off":

GPIO.output(17, False)

```
try:
options = ibmiotf.application.ParseConfigFile("/home/pi/device.cfg")
options["deviceId"] = options["id"]
options["id"] = "aaa" + options["id"]
client = ibmiotf.application.Client(options)
client.connect()
client.deviceEventCallback = myCommandCallback
client.subscribeToDeviceEvents(event="light")        

while True:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(18, GPIO.FALLING)
    print "Button Pushed"
    myData = {'buttonPushed' : True}
    client.publishEvent("raspberrypi", options["deviceId"], "input", "json", myData)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

except ibmiotf.ConnectionException  as e:
    print e

Comment: Can you add your code and python version?  Have you checked firewall/internet connectivity from the Pi?

Comment: I can able to ssh to my pi.

Comment: ssh to the pi only says the pi is on your subnet. When on the pi, make sure it can ping 1tlj3z.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com. But Valerie is probably right and you should upgrade python.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your error is due to the fact you are not using Python and OpenSSL versions to support TLS v1.2 which is required by IoT Platform for encrypted connections.

When you use secure MQTT messaging on ports 8883 or 443, newer client libraries automatically trust the certificate that is presented by Watson IoT Platform. If this is not the case for your client environment, you can download and use the full certificate chain from [messaging.pem](https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-python/blob/master/src/ibmiotf/messaging.pem)

Refer to IoT [TLS security requirements documentation](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/reference/security/connect_devices_apps_gw.html#tls_requirements)

Were you originally running the script to a non-SSL port?  Do you have a wildcard in the domain?